# SSRS Visual Studio 2017 - Grouped by date, but same date showing separately

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a report that displays the returned items in a date range. I have configured the report to be grouped by the returned date and checked the box for the page break between each instance of a group so that each page of the report will display items with each returned date.

When I preview the report, only the first page displays the date and the items returned on the date. From the second page and on, the report displays one item per date, even though there are multiple items with the same date. It just shows all the items separately on each page with the same date.

I tried grouping the items, but it still did not work.

Below is how the report is set up right now. The [ActionDate] is the only one that is grouped.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an example of the records?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the report design.

Comment: Its look OK on the face of it. Have you checked that the ActionDate group is only grouping by date. Also, is the date, just a date or a date time? If it's date time and the times are different then you will need to convert it to just a date in your grouping expression. If this doesn't hep, post some sample data, preferably as a script, so I can test but I can;t see anything wrong from what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your row groups under the main design window.

You will have at least

- one group for your returned date. This should only be grouped on the columns you want to exclude from the detail (in your case probably just returned date)
- You should also have a details group (the icon to the left of the group name will be 3 lines rather than a '['. This details group should have no grouping
- If you have any more groups listed, check if they are needed

Here's a sample of a report design with a single group (in this case email) and a details row group (which has not grouping).

[image]

If this does not help, edit your question and show a screen shot of you report design including the row groups panel and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added a screenshot of the report design.